# Get one random sample for each group and end with a stratified sample pandas

Tags: python, pandas, random

I'm working with a dataframe like this:

```
group    period
  A      20130101
  A      20130201
  .          .
  E      20130901
  E      20131001
```

Let's say I have 100 different groups and 10 possible dates, which are distributed like this: `[.1,.05,.2,.05,.1,.1,.2,.05,.05,.1]`. I need to get *one* sample for each group, so 10% of the final sample is obtained from the first period, 5% from the second period, 20% fom the third period, and so on. I managed to get a random sample for each group, but it's heavily skewed, like this:

```
fn = lambda obj: obj.loc[np.random.choice(obj.index, 1, replace=False),:]
dfrd = df[['group','period']].groupby('group', as_index=False).apply(fn)
dfrd.index = [index[1] for index in dfrd.index]
```

So, is there any way to do something similar, but stratified? Thanks

Comment: The `period` column looks like date. Where did you get the `.1, .05, .2` periods from?

Comment: Those are not periods, it's the distribution of said periods. So, if `20130101` is the first date, I'm saying 10% of rows belong to `20130101`, 5% belong to `20130201` , and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `p` parameter from `np.random.choice`:

```
df1 = (df
      .groupby('grp')
      .apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x['period'].values, size=1, p=prob)[0])
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={0:'period'}))

  grp      period
0   A  2013-01-03
1   B  2013-01-04
2   C  2013-01-04
3   D  2013-01-03
```

> **Sample Data**

```
period = list(map(str, pd.date_range(start='20130101', freq='D', periods=10).date))
grp = sorted(['A','B','C','D']*10)
prob = [.1,.05,.2,.05,.1,.1,.2,.05,.05,.1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'grp': grp, 'period': period*4})
```

Comment: Seems like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll see if it works and report!

Comment: I'm having this error: `ValueError: 'a' and 'p' must have same size`. I'm guessing it is because not every group has data for each date. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: do all the groups have same set of dates ?

Comment: No. There's also more columns, so generating them shouldn't be an option. Periods range from jan-2013 from may-2019 (77 in total) and each group might be associated with 3 to 30+ periods

Comment: I constructed a solution based on your answer, so I'll mark it as the correct one. I iterated many times over this code and filled the iteratively alloted rows per period.